# PHP artisan command no response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

[image]

I tried running other php artisan commands too but still not getting any response. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment file is not usually pushed to repo.

Make sure you'd also put ".env" file at root path. also add DB information.

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back the migration using `php artisan migrate:rollback` and then run the command again